# Read properties of a script which is returned when my page is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, tracking

i'm running a react app and when i render the main page except from the bundle and some other files i get this javascript script called `https://grcontent.experience-booking.com/file/localhost_script.js`:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-101203313-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-101203313-3');
</script>
```

In my main js file i want somehow to access the url inside this script but i don't know how to do this? The reason i want to do this is to execute another script with the 'UA-101203313-3' as property. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `querySelector`, and do something like this to get the URL

*Note, I changed the script src url so it would actually be called*

```js
var tag = document.querySelector('script[src^="https://www.googletagmanager"]');
var url = tag.src;
console.log(url)

// and one could also very simple get the id, like this
var params = (new URL(tag.src)).searchParams;
console.log(params.get("id"))
```

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager_oops.com/gtag/js?id=UA-101203313-3"></script>
```

Comment: i got the error that document.querySelect is not a function

Comment: @user7334203 Updated with working sample...and I initially misspelled it :)

Answer (score 1):

you could retrieve all the script tags from the page and loop through them to find the correct one and parse the `src` attribute. Something like:

```
var scripts = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script'));

for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
   var script = scripts[i];
   if (script.src && script.src.startsWith('https://www.googletagmanager.com') ){
      return getIdFromSrc(script.src);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would one want all that unnecessary workload when it all can be done with a single call?

Comment: clearly some solutions are better than others, and yours was better in this case. /shrug